# firebase admob error with swift3

Tags: firebase, admob, swift3, xcode8

I was using admob in swift 2 without any errors but now in swift 3 when I archive app there are 2 errors,

section "_textcoal_nt" is deprecated 
and 
section "_consta_coal" is deprecated

This only happens when I integrate firebase and admob in my project

I don't know how to solve this problem, has any one got this ? and if you know any other idea how to add admob to swift 3 ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try running pod update:- https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/announcing-firebase-36-for-ios.html

Comment: did not work :(

Comment: I am having the same exact same problems with adsense as well. I suppose we can submit a bug report to Google https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: i have already sent the report still waiting for reply

Answer (score 0):

I have filed a bug report and received a statement from the Google Ads team. They have been able to reproduce the problem. The bug will be corrected in a future release of the SDK. However, there is no ETA at this point.

Comment: so we have to wait untill next release :(

Comment: @NinderChand yeah I guess. I don't know if a build will be rejected by Apple if it has these warnings.